# The difference in syntax for updating an object item

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

What is the difference between:

```
 cartItem = {...cartItem, amount: newAmount}
```

and

```
cartItem.amount = newAmount
```

Comment: I don't think there is any. But the second would be more normal if you want to update the `amount` property

Comment: Well there is a difference: With the first one you create a new object, with second you update the existing object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is an *assignment* to `cartItem`, while the second is a *mutation* of the object held by `cartItem`.

The first creates a *new* object. The previous value of `cartItem` referenced an object that could still be referenced by another reference. Demo:

```js
let newAmount = 13;
let cartItem = { name: "cart", amount: 42 };
let myRef = cartItem;
cartItem = {...cartItem, amount: newAmount};
console.log(myRef); // still the old object

// Let's do this again, with the other technique
cartItem = { name: "cart" };
myRef = cartItem;
cartItem.amount = newAmount;
console.log(myRef); // the mutated object
```

So there is a difference which can be noticeable when you have another  reference to the original object.

This other reference, could be a variable of the caller of a function:

```js
function assignment(cartItem, newAmount) {
    cartItem =  {...cartItem, amount: newAmount};
}

function mutation(cartItem, newAmount) {
    cartItem.amount =  newAmount;
}

// scenario 1
let cartItem = { name: "cart", amount: 42 };
assignment(cartItem, 13);
console.log(cartItem); // Has not changed -- "old" object

// scenario 2
mutation(cartItem, 13);
console.log(cartItem); // Has changed -- "old" object has mutated!
```

Comment: Thanks for such a well explained and complete answer. Much appreciated.